# Unhandles promise rejection when API returns 504

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am getting data from an external API. Sometimes the API return 504. In that time I got 500 error of unhandles promise rejection.

```
let data = await queryData([titleName]);

function queryData(titles) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getData(titles, (err, data) => {
      if (err) reject();
      if (!data) reject();
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
}


getData(titles) {
  // API call which returns 504
}
```

How can I handle the rejection?

Comment: .catch usually with promises or try/catch when using async/wait

Comment: Well *can* you handle the API failure? What should your code do when an error occurs? We cannot tell you that.